# Limpiar carrito Woocommerce al cerrar el navegador

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Quisiera que el al cerrar el navegador pudiera limpiar el carrito de compra, que los productos ingresados puedan limpiarse. Logre hacerlo cuando llegas al index, pero requiero que sea al cerrar el navegador.

Comment: Hola te saludo tu pregunta fue reportada como "baja calidad" te sugiero modificarla con respecto al documento [ask]. Te invito a leer el [tour] del sitio, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

¿Y has probado utilizar este fragmento en tu index?:

```
<? php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["session"]);
```

Se trata de destruir la session anterior al volver a entrar en la página, después de haberla cerrado.

Links utiles:

- http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php
- http://php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php
- http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php

Basado en la respuesta de kpp en inglés:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24402326